# Can Python read this Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

The tried to open an excel file in Python, but it contains a filter in the first row (Image 1), it causes an error in Python that it cannot read it. I tried to use `skiprow` and changing the `.xlsx` file to `.csv`, but that filter from the first row sticks. Is there any way I can read the file without manually deleting that row?

In Excel I have many sheets and they are all with filters in the first row, below is the example of these filters

[image: Image 1]

Comment: You can skip it if you don't need the first line. And u can give a small file example.

Comment: To use `skiprow`, Python needs to read the file first, but with the filter it can't read it, it doesn't load any data

Comment: Actually, Pandas can read excel files with column filters. It just ignores the filters when reading. Maybe you're facing a different problem. What exactly is the message error you're getting?

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva It does not give me error. I tried to pass the data without the filter to another Excel and managed to pass it to Python, that's why I deduce that the problem is those filters, I don't think Python ignores them

Comment: what code to you use to read the file?  `pd.read_excel('filename. xlsx', sheetname='sheetname')` should read excel files ignoring filters.  Can you share more why you think you getting an error?

Comment: @yulGM thanks you, that works. You are a genious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a duplicate of that excel file, remove the filter and then try again.

You can check out this documentation on how to read excel files.
[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Something like this:

```
pd.read_excel(open('tmp.xlsx'),sheet_name='Sheet1')
```